# C++ why the assignment operator should return a const ref in order to avoid (a=b)=c

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I am reading a book about C++ and more precisely about the operator overloading.

The example is the following:

```
const Array &Array::operator=(const Array &right)
{
// check self-assignment
// if not self- assignment do the copying
return *this; //enables x=y=z
}
```

The explanation provided by the book about returning const ref instead of ref is to avoid assignments such as (x=y)=z. I don't understand why we should avoid this. I understand that x=y is evaluated first in this example and since it returns a const reference the =z part cannot be executed. But why?

Comment: Which book?  That looks like an unnecessary precaution to me.  I can't imagine somebody writing `(x=y)=z` -- why would they?  And without the parens, `x=y=z` is parsed as `x=(y=z)`, which makes perfect sense, so there's no risk there.

Comment: But why what? Why is it a const ref? Why is it executed in this order? Why can't `z` be assigned to (x=y)?

Comment: @antronis: get a better C++ book.

Comment: it's deitel c++ how to program 7th edition

Comment: I agree that it's not something you would usually write, but what if you meant `(x = y) == z` and mistyped? I'm not endorsing that particular expression either, but making more things const helps turn runtime errors into compile time errors, which is generally helpful.

Comment: I think this is a bad idea. When defining our own types we try and make the operators behave in the same way as the built-in types behave (so that it is not a surprise to users of the code how they work). If you try the code replacing `Array` with `int` it works. Your code should work in the same way.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`(x=y)` means `x.operator=(y)`, which returns the object `x`. Therefore, `(x=y)=z` means `(x.operator=(y)).operator=(z)`. The expression in parens sets `x` to `y` and returns `x`, and then the outer bit sets `x` to `z`. It does not set `y` to `z` as you might expect, and as the expression `x = y = z` does.

This behavior is counter-intuitive (they should all be equal after the assignment, right?); returning a const reference makes it impossible and avoids the problem.

Comment: While the behavior sounds counter-intuitive, it isn't a "problem" because it is something the programmer would have intentionally done (Which is why they used brackets)

Comment: Who would expect `(x=y)=z` to set `y` to `z`? This is very contrived "problem" and a C++ book shouldn't spend time explaining precautions against it. `(x=5)=z` doesn't set `5` to `z`.

Comment: If you expect assignment to be associative (like comparison is), you would expect all three to be equal at the end. Naive, but a reasonable first-glance interpretation. I agree that this form shouldn't generally be used and shouldn't be emphasized in the book, but it's good to help the compiler help you *not* shoot yourself in the foot whenever possible =)

Comment: The first thing to be understood about assignment is that it is not associative. Every imperative programming textbook that I've seen explains that in chapter 1 or 2. Your comment about mistyping `(x=y) == z` makes more sense.

Comment: It may not be intuitive. **BUT** it is exactly the way it works with integers. I think mimicking the behavior of the standard types is more important than trying to protect people from obscure situations.

Comment: I want to be able to do: `(SelectedMesh = Mesh1).SetTexture(tex);` or `(Normal = l1.Cross(l2)).Normalize();` . What benefits gives me to return a const in such assignments?

Comment: In support of @MartinYork is Donnie Pinkston at CalTech who says in his C++ Operator Overloading Guidelines, http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html, '''The rule of thumb is, "If it's good enough for ints, it's good enough for user-defined data-types."

Answer (score 23):

There is no need to avoid this, unless the book is aimed at programmers that commonly write `(x=y)=z` when they mean `x=y=z`. In practice, nobody in their right mind writes that, so the precaution is entirely unnecessary. It also forbids some other terse constructs, such as `(x=y).nonConstMember()`, that hardly anyone writes but that might be useful in some contexts (although they shouldn't be over-used).

@ybungalobill is right, get a better book.

Comment: +1. A programmer "accidentally" writing `(x=y)=z` seems about as likely (and as necessary to guard against) as a programmer accidentally writing `x=y+system("rm -rf /")` when they meant `x=y`.

Comment: But I have seen `if ((x = y) = z) ...` when the author meant `if ((x = y) == z) ...`.

Answer (score 14):

As far as I know, assignment operators do not return const references in idiomatic C++. The Standard types do not return const references either.

```
std::string a, b, c;
(a = b).clear(); // no objection from compiler
```

All of my custom assignment operators have returned a non-const reference.

When in doubt, check the Standard library. It's not flawless, but it definitely gets basic things like this correct.

Comment: The Boost folk commonly return mutable refs, too.

Answer (score 4):

I would look at the behavior of the built-in types.

When defining your own types it is preferable that the operators behave the same way as the built-in types. This allows easy adoption of your classes without having to dig into your code to see why they behave differently from expected.

So if we look at integers:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    int y = 6;
    int z = 7;

    (x = y) = z;
    std::cout << x << " " << y << " " << z << "\n";
}
```

This works with y unchanged and x being assigned 7. In your code i would expect your assignment operator to work the same way. The standard assignment operator definition:

```
Array& Array::operator=(Array const& rhs)
{
    /* STUFF */
    return *this;
}
```

Should do that just fine (assuming /* STUFF */ is correct).

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can see is that this book was written to explain C++ to C programmers (or by an author whose C understanding is better than C++ understanding). Because for a C programmer, the expression `(x = y) = z` is invalid for built-in types, and he probably will to try to get the same behavior with its user-defined types.

However, C and C++ are different languages, and in C++ the expression `(x = y) = z` is valid even for built-in types. So if you want to have the same behavior for your user-defined types, you should return a non-const reference in the `operator =`.

I would advise you to get a better book, one that does not make the confusion between C and C++. They are not the same langages, even if they derive from a common base.