# Chaining operator= for write-only objects - OK to return rhs instead of *this?

Tags: c++, pointers, operators

It's well known that `operator=` should return a <strike>const</strike> reference to `*this` to support chaining, but this only works if `*this` <strike>can be used as an rvalue</strike> is value-like.

**Edit:** Fine, `operator=` should return a non-const reference (do as the `int`s), and I meant that `*this` needs to be a meaningful `rhs` in an assignment.

I'm wrapping a C API of name=value setter functions through a C++ class `ApiWrapper` with `operator[]` returning a temporary write-only `Proxy` with overloaded `operator=`, but the API has no getter functions so `Proxy` is effectively write-only.

```c++
ApiWrapper x;
x["a"] = x["b"] = 42;  // x["b"] = 42;      fine:  consumes 42, returns *this
                       // x["a"] = x["b"];  error: x["b"] does not have the value
```

It seems to me that if I return a const reference to `rhs` instead of `*this` from `operator=`, chaining would work fine. Conceptually (proxy boilerplate code left out):

```c++
struct Proxy {
    template <typename T>
    T const& operator=(T const& rhs) const
    {
        ...         // pass rhs to the API but don't store it
        return rhs; // return rhs, not *this
    }
};

ApiWrapper x;
x["a"] = x["b"] = 42;  // x["b"] = 42;   fine: consumes and returns 42
                       // x["a"] = 42;   fine: consumes and returns 42
```

This makes me suspicious though. Are there any weird side effects from returning a const reference to `rhs` instead of `*this`? The only thing I can think of is that I won't be able to use it in expressions like `(x["a"] = 42).doSomething()` but my `Proxy` cannot support anything like that anyway, since it is write-only. Or would it be better to just disallow chaining (e.g. by returning `void`)?

**Edit:** Even if `Proxy` is not value-like, I think supporting assignment makes sense, it allows syntactic sugar like:

```c++
// this:                          // rather than:
ApiWrapper w;                     API * ptr = make_api_instance();
w["name"] = "Batman";             api_set_str(ptr, "name", "Batman");
w["age"]  = 42;                   api_set_int(ptr, "age", 42);
w["pi"]   = 3.14;                 api_set_double(ptr, "pi", 3.14);
```

Comment: The copy assignment operator should return a non-const reference.

Comment: How can `operator =` be `const`?

Comment: Your opening statement doesn't really make sense. First off, assignment can't be `const` and neither should the return value be. Second, `*this` is *always* an lvalue (since it's dereferencing a pointer), and there's always the standard lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, if `operator=` returns a non-const reference, you allow `(a=b)=c;` , see eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706690/c-why-the-assignment-operator-should-return-a-const-ref-in-order-to-avoid-a-b.

Comment: @AndersJohansson Which is *exactly* what it's supposed to do.

Comment: @AndyProwl, I made `operator=` const because it is a proxy; the proxy itself does not change through assignment.

Comment: @KerrekSB, the point is that the proxy does not have anything to return from a conversion operator, therefore there cannot be any.

Comment: I'm not sure now what your question is. Your second piece of code more or less seems to work. What's the problem?

Comment: And why can't you give the proxy class itself a sensible copy-assignment operator?

Comment: @KerrekSB Because "it's well known the assignment operator returns a const reference" ;)

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: How could I forget :-)

Comment: I'm just asking whether returning `rhs` makes sense at all or if I'm overlooking something major. A proxy copy constructor/assignment operator wouldn't work because the only thing it could do would be to make `x["a"]` refer to the same underlying API property as `x["b"]` which is not what is intended by chaining them.

Comment: @AndersJohansson: Well, if your objects are fundamentally not value-like, i.e. if it doesn't make sense to "give one the semantics of another" (like a thread or a network socket), then you probably shouldn't allow *any* assignment or copy operations.

Comment: @AndersJohansson Any member function that takes a const-ref parameter and returns that same const-ref parameter is subject to **undefined behavior**. Just don't do it.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, thanks! That's a very good point I hadn't thought of - if the const-ref parameter is a temporary, it won't persist after I return it.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Why exactly is that?

Comment: @jogojapan Because as Anders mentioned you can pass in a temporary object that gets destroyed after the function returns leaving you with a dangling reference.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious But that's the responsibility of the person who passes it a temporary.

Comment: @jogojapan IMHO that's a careless attitude and one reason UB happens as often as it does. If you _need_ to pass a temporary add a move assignment operator.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Sure, I didn't say it's good design. But returning a const-reference that you were passed doesn't as such cause undefined behaviour. The caller will receive a reference to an object that is still alive (because the object lives within the entire full-expression of which the function call is a part). The object dies at the end of that full-expression, not automatically after the return from the function.

Comment: @jogojapan All I said was it is subject to UB. The point is the developer needs to  be aware that the assignment operator can return a reference to a temporary. It's counter-intuitive to the semantics of the operator and requires explicit knowledge of the different. I have a feeling you know better than to do this ;)

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Sure, sure, no disagreement there... I was just irritated by your statement, which seemed to indicate that returning a const-reference as passed is itself UB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your approach makes sense. Just to check if I understand your problem correctly, the struct could look something like this:

```
struct Proxy {
    template <typename T>
    T const& operator=(T const& rhs) const
    {
        send_to_abi(rhs);
        return rhs;
    }
};
```

As you say, since Proxy does not store `rhs` anywhere, and I'm assuming no `receive_from_abi` function exists, then returning `*this` will not work - the number would not be propagated in this case. As the comments point out, some behaviors such as `(a=3)=3` will not work, but that isn't really surprising.

Edit: As the comments point out, this approach is dangerous if `rhs` is a temporary. This can be fixed by returning a copy instead:

```
struct Proxy {
    template <typename T>
    T operator=(T const& rhs) const
    {
        send_to_abi(rhs);
        return rhs;
    }
};
```

This might appear expensive `a["a"] = a["b"] = a["c"] = foo` looks like it would involve 3 copies. But these should be avoidable through a common compiler optmimization.

Comment: `const Proxy& a = b = Proxy(); a.BlowUp();`

Comment: Yes that is exactly it - `rhs` is passed to another function but not stored and not retrievable later. However Captain Obvlious is right, I can't return rhs if it's a temporary.

Comment: Yes, he's right. You could return a copy, which would not necessarily be expensive. The other solution also involves copies, but it is easier for the compiler to optimize copies when returning than internally stored copies when they occur in this kind of chain, I think. So how about using this approach, but changing the signature to ``T operator=(T const& rhs) const``? Of course, that would not work for objects without a copy constructor.

Comment: Accepting this answer since it is more in line with the spirit of what I'm asking for in the question (though after the discussion, I'm leaning more toward just disallowing chaining instead). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the cleanest solution would be to stick with the standard idioms. If you make your proxy class copy-constructible and copy-assignable in the usual way, this should work. Something like this:

```
struct Proxy
{
    Proxy(Proxy const & rhs)
    : // ...
    {
        // copy internal state of rhs
    }

    Proxy & operator=(Proxy const & rhs)
    {
        // copy internal state of rhs
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename T>
    Proxy & operator=(T const & rhs)
    {
        // ... perform T-specific operations ... #1
        return *this;
    }
};
```

An additional benefit is that whatever "generic logic" has to be performed by the first assignment at #1 doesn't need to be repeated in every subsequent assignment.

Comment: The internal state of the proxy is just the parent API wrapper and the name of the property. With the above `x["name"] = x["address"]` would make the proxy for "name" refer to the same property as the proxy for "address" does, which is not correct.

Comment: He is a bit unclear, but I interpreted this as adding an extra variable to ``Proxy``, which would store the last assigned value. When assigning a proxy to a proxy, the stored value in the RHS proxy (42 in this case) would then be used. It is a bit redundant (42 being stored both in Proxy and in the underlying api.

Comment: @amaurea, nice idea but it counteracts the point of the proxy (which is to accept assignment of any type and call the correct API function depending on that type). To store the value, `Proxy` would have to be a template class instead of `operator=` being a template function, and `ApiWrapper::operator[]` would have to return `Proxy` objects of the correct type. Alternatively use `boost::any` or `void*` or something ugly like that.