# Return type of assignment operator

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

When defining an assignment operator, it invariably looks like this:

```
class X {...};

X& X::operator=(...whatever...);
```

That is, it has the return type "reference to X". Here, parameters (`...whatever...`) can be `X&`, [`const X&`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15292974/509868), just `X` when using the [copy-and-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3279543/509868), or any other type.

It seems strange that [everyone recommends returning a non-const reference to `X`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4706690/509868), regardless of the parameters. This explicitly allows expressions like [`(a = b).clear()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4706811/509868), which is supposed to be good.

I have a different opinion, and I want to disallow expressions like `(x=y).clear`, `(x=y)=z`, and even `x=y=z` in my code. My idea is that these expressions do too complex things on a single line of code. So I decided to have my assignment operators return `void`:

```
void X::operator=(X) {...}
void X::operator=(int) {...}
```

Which negative effects does this have? (except looking different than usual)

Can my class X be used with standard containers (e.g. `std::vector<X>`)?

I am using C++03 (if that matters).

Comment: agreed, I missed from beginning.

Comment: There is an overarching recommendation in C++: *overloaded operators should behave similarly as they would on integers*. Chaining is possible on integers (`a = b = c = 3`), and thus one should preserve this syntactic possibility when overloading.

Comment: @MatthieuM. +1. Of course, as always, good rules have even better exceptions: `<<` on streams comes to mind.

Comment: @Angew: actually, it might be strange, because I never really did C much, and thus for me `<<` is primarily a streaming operator and it happens that some weird dude decided to use it for bit shifting :)

Comment: You shouldn't unnecessarily restrict the coding style of your users, no matter how bad you think it might be. Consider they make a template function, and try to use your class. It may no longer compile if your operators no longer work in the expected way.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your class does not meet the [CopyAssignable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CopyAssignable) concept (§17.6.3.1) so it is no longer guaranteed by the standard to work with the standard containers that require this (e.g. `std::vector` requires this for `insert` operations).

Besides that, this behavior is not idiomatic and will be perceived as surprising by programmers using your code. If you want to disallow chaining, consider adding a named function that does the assignment instead.

Just don't try to change the behavior of idiomatic operators in subtle ways like this. It will make your code harder to read and maintain.