# Don't understand the use of const for functions and classes

Tags: c++, constructor, constants, variable-assignment, operator-keyword

Can someone please explain the use of const when its being used in function declarations and classes? I understand that if a function returns a const variable/object, then that thing can not be used on the left side of an assignment operator? Is this correct? Also, i noticed that if you were to do:

```
int x = 1;
int &i = x;
```

The above code would not compile unless i were a "constant reference" to the int. For functions, do the arguments passed into the function parameters have to be constant if the parameters are declared constant?

One example of my book has the following code:

```
const Array &Array::operator=(const Array &right)
{
if (&right != this) //avoid self assignment
  //blah blah
return *this; //enables x = y = z for example
}
```

Why does this function permit the object Array assignments such as x = y  = z but prevents ones like (x = y) = z?? The book's reasoning is "because z cannot be assigned to the const Array reference that's returned by (x = y). But in the first case, doesn't x = y also return a constant Array reference???

Also, when you do assign 1 object of a class to another, the compiler uses member wise assignment unless the the user provides a default copy constructor, in which case THAT is invoked right?

Thankyou so much! Sorry I have a lot of specific questions. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: A value of `const`-qualified type cannot be used where a non-`const`-qualified type is expected, like normally on the lhs of an assignment-expression. See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71dfb0ed9bc208d6 for an example of mis-definition of op=.

Comment: The code you said would not compile would indeed compile, why do you think it wouldn't?

Comment: Before writing "the above would not compile", try compiling it !!

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone please explain the use of const when its being used in function declarations and classes?

`const` on a member function means the function can't modify the non-`mutable` data members.  It also means the function can be called on a `const` instance of the class, whereas non-`const` member functions can not.

`const` can also be used on data members - it means they have to be assigned to in the constructor's initialiser list and can not be modified thereafter (even from non-`const` member functions).

> [`int x = 1; int &i = x;` would not compile unless...

Yes it does.  What you can't do is this: `const int x = 1; int &i = x;` - you can't do it because such an `i` would incorrectly facilitate a later assignment ala `i = 4;` asking to write to the `const int x`.

> permit the object Array assignments such as `x = y = z` but prevents ones like `(x = y) = z`?

[C++ operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) means `x = y = z` - without parentheses - is equivalent to `x = (y = z)`, so the `(y = z)` assignment yields a `const` value that can still be assigned to the non-`const` object `x`.

That contrasts with `(x = y) = z` where `(x = y)` yields a temporary `const` value that can't be further assigned to (given `Array::operator=` is not a `const` member function, per the rules mentioned above)

> Also, when you do assign 1 object of a class to another, the compiler uses member wise assignment unless the the user provides a default copy constructor, in which case THAT is invoked right?

`default` is the keyword a programmer uses to explicitly ask for a compiler-generated copy constructor, i.e. one that does the member wise assignments.  It's when the user provides their own *user-defined* implementation (or `delete`s the copy constructor) that the default implementation is *not* used.

Comment: Oh, I thought the rules for precedence were from left to right, if the operator is the same? So 1 + 2 + 3 would evaluate as 1 + (2 + 3)? Thanks

Comment: A reference being returned by a function can be used as a lvalue or a rvalue right?
ex: cout << integers1[5]; or integers1[5] = 1000;

Comment: @KevinCheng: `1 + 2 + 3` --> `(1 + 2) + 3`... see the linked page's "Associativity" column where it says which operators are "Left-to-Right" and "Right-to-Left", and note that the relevant operators are "Addition and subtraction", not "Unary plus and minus".

Comment: *"A reference being returned by a function can be used as a lvalue or a rvalue right? ex: `cout << integers1[5];` or `integers1[5] = 1000;`"* - that's right if the returned reference is not `const`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct in assuming that.

`const` is an indication that the data you have is not mutable, this is just a compiler technique though; assembly has not paradigm of 'const-ness'.

(`const_cast` is a good example of this)

Where the `const` is placed on a line is extremely important too, especially for pointers.

e.g.

`const int *ptr` isn't the same as `int const *ptr`

That doesn't apply exactly the same to references though, so I guess that was just a bad example.

---

`const` is also important when defining class methods. Which methods are available when you get a `const&` to an object?

Well, this is a well defined case:

```
#include <iostream>
class shizam{
    public:
        void print() const {std::cout << "const shizam!\n";}
        void print()       {std::cout << "non-const shizam!\n";}
};
```

Then if later on we have a function:

```
void print_shazam(const shizam &ref){
    ref.print();
}
```

That function would print "const shizam!"

but a function

```
void print_shazam(shizam &ref){
    ref.print();
}
```

would print "non-const shizam!"

This is important because then the person defining the class can seperate the methods that can modify the class and those that can't; as I said, `const` is an indication that the data *is not* mutable.

---

This example from the same book:

```
const Array &Array::operator=(const Array &right){
    if(&right != this){ //avoid self assignment
        // blah blah
    }
    return *this; //enables x = y = z for example
}
```

Has already been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706690/c-why-the-assignment-operator-should-return-a-const-ref-in-order-to-avoid-a-b)

Comment: wait, x = const & i and x = & const i is the same thing??

Comment: Neither of those are valid, do you mean `const T &x = i` and `T const &x = i`?

Comment: Yes. Are those the same thing? I did not know references could only be declared 1 time. I thought they were like pointers.

Comment: Yes, they're the same. References themselves aren't mutable, but the data itself is mutable depending on the type of reference.